# Expanding sum of negative power using log

Tags: sequences-and-series

Example expands the series with natural logarithm but I do not know this rules.

$\sum_{a} a^{-n} = \sum_{a}1 - n \sum_{a}log(a) + \cdots $

Anybody understand this expansion? Thank you!

Comment: $$a^{-n}=e^{\ln(a^{-n})}=e^{-n\ln(a)}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^mn^m\ln(a)^m}{m!}=1-n\ln(a)+\frac{n^2\ln(a)^2}{2}+\cdots$$